# What do I need to implement a digital map with GPS and routing support?

Tags: gps, maps, gis

I need to create a digital map with GPS and routing support for a local tour trail project.

I've got the drawing of the map which looks like the following.

[image]

Constraints:

- I cannot use Google Map.
- I need to support GPS.
- I need to show route.

What I think I need to do:

- Collect Latitude and Longitude of all the routes in the map?
- Collect distance of all routes and intersections
- Collect road information
- Use A* algorithm to find shortest path

What else do you think I need to do? It will be a small map with 2km radius.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need more specifics to be really helpful here, but to get you started, I'd recommend that you check out following...

- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) for digitizing your map
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) + [PostGIS](http://postgis.net) for storing your geospatial data
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) if you need to publish the map online

You can import GPS data into QGIS (and other systems) using the GPS Exchange Format (.gpx extension).